# Buscando dados em várias páginas num único site

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou precisando fazer um banco com os dados de alguns produtos de um site. Os detalhes dos produtos (nome, valor, marca) são públicos e divididos em páginas. Cada página exibe aproximadamente 10 produtos e seus dados. Eu preciso criar um programinha que recolha esses dados (que são exibidos em  html) e salve esses valores. De preferência em Javascript ou PHP. Alguém sabe qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso? Como seria feita essa leitura? Como mostrar para o código quais dados buscar?

Comment: Já tentou fazer requisições AJAX?

Comment: Não, Danilo. Na verdade nem tenho muito conhecimento de programação.

Comment: Ao menos já tens algo feito ?

Comment: Oi Edilson. Ainda não sei nem por onde começar. Poderia me dar uma dica?

Comment: Recomendo a leitura de webcrawlers. Além do mais, uma informação estar disponibilizada em um site não necessariamente quer dizer que ela pode ser utilizada fora do site sem permissão.

Comment: Olá Willian, muito obrigado pelas dicas. Vou ler sim. Quanto a utilização dos dados, isso já foi resolvido com o gerente.

Answer (score 0):

Estudando um pouco, resolvi fazer criando uma extensão para o Chrome. Em um arquivo foi criado todo o script que fazia a leitura dos dados. A extensão basicamente inseria esse script na página, capturando os dados utilizando funções simples como `getElementById('profissao').innerText` e em seguida pulava para a página seguinte.

Mais detalhes podem ser encontrados em https://developer.chrome.com/extensions